# Fibocom L850-GL installation on Ubuntu 20.04 or 21.10

Tags: drivers, 20.04, 21.10, 4g

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Nano Gen 1 with the Fibcom L850-GL 4G LTE CAT9 module.

I found some information how to install it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091315/fibocom-l850-gl-installation-on-ubuntu-18-04), but id does not work. Since I cannot comment or answer here a new question.

- This solution gives me errors (incompatible pointers) while
  compiling: https://github.com/xmm7360/xmm7360-usb-modeswitch
- This one ends up with a message `INFO:root:IP address couldn't be fetched, waiting 1 seconds` 
  https://github.com/xmm7360/xmm7360-pci
- Here I got also an error while compiling (`-Werror=implicit-function-declaration`) https://github.com/juhovh/xmm7360_usb

Unfortunately, I don't really have a clue what I'm doing. But as I read, the module should work. Some ideas how I could do this?

Edit: Tried it on Ubuntu 20.04 and upgraded now to 21.10, with the same result

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/xmm7360/xmm7360-pci is the correct one you look for. The m.2 slot in every Thinkpad since I think 2019 or so only supports PCIe and not USB mode anymore.

The IP address error - check if the APN is correct, no PIN and all WIFI is disabled.

Similar questions can be found on Github and one post had it working with X1 Nano. https://github.com/xmm7360/xmm7360-pci/issues/114

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. How do I check if the APN is correct? Respectively how do I find out what it should look like and how can I change it?
What means PIN?

Comment: Sorry => Of course PIN is the Pincode of the Simcard. Did not got that: I never had to enter a PIN. I deactivated the pin on the sim card by inserting it into another phone and setting it that way there. However, I do not know how to do this on Linux. What programs do you need to do this?

Comment: Great, that was easier than I thought. Have now picked out an APN here:
https://www.apnsettings.org/
And I saw that I have to set the APN at the xmm7360.ini- file. I didn't know that I have to configure something in the files. Now it seems to work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: nice you could get it to work!